# Mirroring Mishaps

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I was playing around with the mirror modifier and I found that when I turned off the mirroring, my model turned form this:

[image]

to this:
[image]

Is there a way to turn the body of the model to the other side so when I turn off the mirror modifier only the right side of the model is shown?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because your geometry actually is positioned that way.

To reposition your geometry all on the same side:

1. Position your cursor in the center of the scene (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>*> Snap Cursor to Center*)
2. Set the pivot point to the 3D cursor by pressing <kbd>.</kbd> (period)
3. Select the part(s) of your model that are on the wrong side (hovering and pressing <kbd>L</kbd> to select linked geometry might be helpful)
4. Press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd>
5. Remove double vertices (<kbd>W</kbd>*> Remove Doubles*)
6. You may also need to recalculate normals after this (<kbd>A</kbd>*> Select all* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>)